# Can't log in to chat with OpenID and Firefox

Tags: support, chat, login

I recently got logged out of chat somehow, and now I am locked out.

When I try to log into my [chat.stackexchange.com account](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) it asks me to log in. On the global chat login page, it says, "If automatic login fails, please visit the GlobalAuth test & help page to check for common problems." I visit that page and it says that everything is fine. It suggests that I log out of my main account, which I do, and that I remove all my stackexchange.com cookies, which I do.

I can log into my [math.stackexchange.com account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn), and my [stackexchage.com account](https://stackexchange.com/users/512484/robjohn), but going to a chat site still asks me to log in and fails.

I am running Firefox 16.0.1 and MacOS X 10.5.8 and use a Google OpenID. This has all worked before.

**Note:** I *can* log into my [chat.meta.stackexchange.com account](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/174208/robjohn).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Okay, so I added a StackExchange.com account to my logins and I can get back onto chat. Thanks.